# How do we draw parallels between the BBG drug example and the businessman (affected by the election) anecdote in "The book of why"?

Tags: references, simpsons-paradox, paradox

In "The book of why", Dr Pearl concludes that a BBG drug cannot exist after phrasing the sure-thing principle in 'a more correct way' (pg 214). He does this by first "insisting" that the businessman's decision has no effect on the election, thus making the sure thing principle valid.

> To make the sure-thing principle valid, we must insist that the
> businessman’s decision will not affect the outcome of the election. As
> long as the businessman is sure his decision won’t affect the
> likelihood of a Democratic or Republican victory, he can go ahead and
> buy Property B. Otherwise, all bets are off. Note that the missing
> ingredient (which Savage neglected to state explicitly) is a causal
> assumption. A correct version of his principle would read as follows:
> an action that increases the probability of a certain outcome assuming
> either that Event C occurred or that Event C did not occur will also
> increase its probability if we don’t know whether C occurred… provided
> that the action does not change the probability of C. In particular,
> there is no such thing as a BBG drug.

My question is this- How do we draw a parallel between the businessman anecdote and the BBG drug phenomenon and what is event C in each case?

My suppositions are-

- the decision to take the drug or not = decision to buy property or not
- elected party = gener

Thereby- If the action of taking a drug changes the probability of the taker to be male or female, then the 'sure-thing' principle does not hold.